# Concatenating all arguments of a function/removing all spaces from a variable

Tags: shell-script, variable

What's a good way to concatenate all arguments of a function?

What I got at the moment is iterating over them and appending them consecutively:

```
func(){
concat=
for arg in "$@"
do
    concat=$concat$arg
done
echo $concat
}
```

I'd like to potentially do something like:

```
another_func() {
echo $(remove_spaces $@)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
concat () (
    IFS=''
    printf '%s\n' "$*"
)
```

This function uses `"$*"` (the double quotes are important), which will expand to a single string with the values of the positional parameters (the arguments) concatenated with the value of the first character of `$IFS` as delimiter.

We set `IFS` to an empty string, which means `"$*"` would expand to all the arguments concatenated without a delimiter.

Also note that we protect the rest of the shell script from adopting the changed `$IFS` value by enclosing it in a subshell `( ... )` instead of the usual `{ ... }`.

A call to this function could, in another function, look like

```
other_func () {
    printf '%s\n' "$( concat "$@" )"
}
```

or shorter, without actually calling the `concat` function:

```
other_func () {
    ( IFS=''; printf '%s\n' "$*" )
}
```

To delete all spaces in a list of arguments, use

```
printf '%s\n' "$*" | tr -d ' '
```

e.g.,

```
concat_delete_sp () {
    printf '%s\n' "$*" | tr -d ' '
}
```

Testing:

```
$ concat 1 2 3 "h h h" o o o
123h h hooo
```

```
$ concat_delete_sp 1 2 3 "h h h" o o o
123hhhooo
```

Answer (score 0):

For a few-resources-fast-solution with an approach based on your second example:

```
func(){
  a=$@;echo ${a// /}
}
```

By this way you are removing absolutely all the spaces. But have in mind @kusalananda's approach if you plan to have arguments containing spaces.

Comment: This would produce the wrong results if any of the arguments contained a space.  These spaces would also be deleted, so it's not really "concatenating the arguments".

Comment: @Kusalananda I agree but is the example the user asked for as the second example. I assumed he has it foreseen already

Comment: Also note that you would want to double quote variable expansions to avoid issues when calling the function as e.g. `func '*'`

Comment: @Kusalananda I think that if that is the situation, the question should have more details. I assumed his goal is to keep it simple, fast and using the less amount of resources as possible for a very specific problem. If you assume more, you should ask for edit the question with more details

Answer (score 0):

In the `zsh` shell, you can use the `j:separator:` parameter expansion flag to join the elements of an array with an arbitrary separator. So you can do:

```
concat=${(j::)argv}
```

or

```
concat=${(j::)@}
```

to concatenate the elements of the `$argv` aka `$@` array without having to modify a global parameter like `$IFS`.

If it's just to print the arguments, with Bourne-like shells, you can always do:

```
concat() {
  printf %s "$@" || return
  [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '\n' # empty output if no argument
}
```

The `printf` builtin of `bash` and `zsh` can also store the result in a variable with:

```
printf -v variable %s "$@"
```

With the `fish` shell, you can use:

```
echo -s -- $argv
```

(it prints an empty line if `$argv` is an empty list).